# firebase phone auth for browser

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to use firebase phone auth from a PWA/https site.
Ref : `https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth`
From the docs it looks like android based api. Was looking for a chrome or browser based api in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most Firebase products, its Authentication is available for Android, iOS and web. The documentation for the web version can be found at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth